# Does the Atheros AR956X WLAN adapter support WoWLAN (Wake on Wireless LAN)?

Tags: wireless-networking, file-transfer, file-sharing, wake-on-lan, wake-up

Some friends want to be able to access files on their WiFi network, even when one of their computers is asleep.

To accomplish this, they probably need WoWLAN (Wake on Wireless LAN) working.

Does their Atheros AR956X WLAN adapter support WoWLAN (Wake on Wireless LAN) in Windows 7 SP1?

In their Windows 7 SP1 Device Manager, the checkbox to enable WoWLAN is dimmed (grayed).  They tried adding the registry key specified in MS TN851581 to enable this option, but it had no effect.  They also tried adjusting their BIOS settings, but also no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. I use exactly same driver for my wireless network.

Just go to wireless driver properties

Click on the power management tab. You'll see the options you require.

Comment: Thank you so much for confirming.  What version of the driver are you using, and where did you get it?  The option for WoWLAN was unavailable (grayed out / dimmed) in their wireless driver properties page.